# Why is my r2_score dependent on the units of the dependent variable

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, regression, non-linear-regression

I have built a regression model using ANN relating 8 input parameters and 1 output parameter.

code

```
X = data.iloc[:,:-1]
y = data.iloc[:,8:9]*100

# Splitting the dataset into the Training set and Test set
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train_us, X_test_us, y_train_us, y_test_us = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.2, random_state = 0)


# Feature Scaling
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
sc_X = StandardScaler()
sc_Y = StandardScaler()
X_train = sc_X.fit_transform(X_train_us)
X_test = sc_X.transform(X_test_us)

y_train = sc_Y.fit_transform(y_train_us)
y_test = sc_Y.transform(y_test_us)



# Importing the Keras libraries and packages
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasRegressor


def base_model():
    # Initialising the ANN
    regressor = Sequential()   
    # Adding the input layer and the first hidden layer
    regressor.add(Dense(units = 6, kernel_initializer = 'uniform', activation = 'relu', input_dim = 8))   
    # Adding the second hidden layer
    regressor.add(Dense(units = 4, kernel_initializer = 'uniform', activation = 'relu'))   
    # Adding the output layer
    regressor.add(Dense(units = 1, kernel_initializer = 'uniform'))
    # Compiling the ANN
    regressor.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'mse', metrics = ['mae'])
    return regressor

# Fitting the ANN to the Training set
regressor = KerasRegressor(build_fn=base_model, epochs=500, batch_size=32)
regressor.fit(X_train,y_train)

# Predicting the Test & Train set with regressor built
y_pred = regressor.predict(X_test)
y_pred = sc_Y.inverse_transform(y_pred)
y_test = sc_Y.inverse_transform(y_test)

#calculate r2_score
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score
score_test = r2_score(y_test,y_pred)
```

I get an r2_score of 98%.Unit of my output variable is currently metres. If I multiply it by 100 and change it to centi-meters and train the model and calculate the r2_score it is 91%.

Why is my r2_score changing with the unit of the dependent variable. Shouldn't scaling take care of this?

Thanks!!